# JPA repository findBySOMETHING, could not extract result

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lob

I'm using JPA repository for some toy project, I want to get List of object SOMETHING, but result is `could not extract ResultSet; SQL[n/a]`.

This is my object (nothing is important, just focus on lob plz)

```
{
    ...
    private Long id

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String content;
    ...
}
```

Then, I use repository to `findByContentLike("CONTENT")`, then result is failed, the reason is that cannot extract result.

why this happened? even i set on `application.properties` like `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true`

there anyone know about this error? please bring me to the light.

Comment: You have to provide the wildcard characters (i.e `findByContentLike("%CONTENT%")`)  see here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries)

Answer (score 0):

If you need auto parameter bound wrapped in `%`(wildcard) use

`findByContentContaining("Content")`

Or you need to manually add `%`(wildcard) in the string

`findByContentLike("%Content%")`

Answer (score 0):

JPA-methodqueries require a special syntax. Most commonly they are build up as: `findBy` + a field of your entity. In your case, the `like` is redundant.

See this [reference to the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories) for examples.

As complexity increases, you might want to write your own queries, using JPQL. A small example:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p "
            + "LEFT JOIN p.categories category "
            + "WHERE UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', COALESCE(:searchRequest, ''), '%')) "
            + "AND UPPER(p.description) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', COALESCE(:description, ''), '%')) "
            + "AND p.price BETWEEN :priceLow AND :priceHigh "
            + "AND p.averageRating >= :averageRating "
            + "AND p.archived = :archived "
            + "AND ((category.name IN :selectedCategories) "
            + "OR (:amountOfSelectedCategories = 0 AND category IN (SELECT c FROM Category c))) "
            + "GROUP BY p "
            + "HAVING SIZE(p.categories) >= :amountOfSelectedCategories"
    )
    Page<Product> findAllBySearchModel(
            Pageable pageable,
            @Param("searchRequest") String searchRequest,
            @Param("description") String description,
            @Param("priceLow") BigDecimal priceLow,
            @Param("priceHigh") BigDecimal priceHigh,
            @Param("averageRating") double averageRating,
            @Param("archived") boolean archived,
            @Param("selectedCategories") List<String> selectedCategories,
            @Param("amountOfSelectedCategories") int amountOfSelectedCategories
    );
```

Don't forget to mark your entity class with `@Entity` and to have your repository extend `JpaRepository<MyEntityClass, Long>` where the Long corresponds with your entity's `@Id` field.